# How do I maintain my app's background while a website is being displayed?

Tags: background, themes, codenameone

When my app redirects to a web page the background (particularly the stuff near the top) becomes very condensed and I don't know why. It's almost as if the screen is pushing everything closer to the top in order to make room for the website view. How do I avoid this? Right now I have a center border on the website view.

ex: website.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, browser);

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read about [peer components](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html#native-peer-components) which indicate some of the limitations of peers. Even though we are are [revisiting this](http://www.codenameone.com/blog/new-android-peer-mode.html) the core concepts and limits still apply.

Things get pushed because of layout and separation of scrolling behavior. If you stick stuff in the NORTH you will have the website and the content competing for the same space.